# Drive info based on server name selection from combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, driveinfo

C#: Cascading combobox

I have ComboBox that loaded with three servers name. I want to retrieve drive info on each server based on user's option of the server name in the combobox.
I have another combobox that should be populated with the drive on each server.

Any idea how I could accomplish that?

I am connecting to the server with connection string:

```
 string ConnectionString = "data source = ServerName;Integrated Security=True"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your Connection String missing Database name,user id and password .

Example:

```
string ConnectionString = "data source = ServerName;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=True;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```